# C++ Compilation flags in CLION?

Tags: c++, cmake, compilation, g++, clion

I have created a new `C++11` project in the latest available version of Clion and ran it locally which gave me no errors at all.

**But,** when I ran it on an external server with the following line:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -DNDEBUG -Wall *.cpp
```

I got few error (which I was able to correct them later).

My question is how can I prevent this from happening? I want Clion to compile it as strict as the server does.

Here are the contents of `CMakeLists.txt` in my project:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)
project(my_first)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

add_executable(my_first main.cpp)
```

Comment: Please do a minimum of research in the cmake documentation. You want the `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` option.

Comment: I found this: set(GCC_COVERAGE_COMPILE_FLAGS "-Wall") but where I should add it at which line? plus should I add anything else?

Comment: Any help please?

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your Cmakelists.txt, right after you set CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS -Wall)
```

Comment: Someone mentions adding this too: set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${GCC_COVERAGE_COMPILE_FLAGS}" ) is it correct?

Comment: here: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000004970-Add-Compiler-Flags

Comment: It's another way of accomplishing the same, but I doubt you are going to run gcov any time soon.